# How can I check that a SQL query has no result?

Tags: java, android, sql

As written in the title, I check my SQL database with following method:

```
public String[] getRecord(String category){
        String[] record = new String[3];
        Cursor crsRecord = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(QUERY_GET_RECORD + category, null);
        int i=0;

        while(crsRecord.moveToNext()){
            record[i] = crsRecord.getString(0);
            i++;
        }

        return record;

    }
```

Now it could be that the line:

```
Cursor crsRecord = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(QUERY_GET_RECORD + category, null);
```

has no result, because I have no appropriate data in my database. How can I check that I have no result?

Answer (score 2):

```
cursor.moveToFirst();

if (cursor.isAfterLast()){
    // You have no results
}
```

Or, you could just change your code to this:

```
while(!crsRecord.isAfterLast()){

    // Instead of using an int literal to get the colum index,
    // use the getColumnIndex method
    int index = crsRecord.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);
    if (index == -1) {
        // You don't have the column-- do whatever you need to do.
    }
    else {
        record[i] = crsRecord.getString(index);
        i++;
    }

    crsRecord.moveToNext();
}
```

If there are no records, the while loop never starts.

Comment: What is when I don't have even the column in my database for which I was asking for? Then I got the error in the cursor line.

Comment: Alternatively, use the for-loop idiom: `for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {`